# Rails create additional create action and redirect new to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let say I want to create an additional create action. Let's call it create2.

items_controller:

```
def new 
@item = Item.new
and

def create
.....
end

def create2
.....
end
```

items/form:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@item) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<%= end %>
```

routes:

```
post 'create2', to: 'items#create2', as: :create2
```

Once I submit form, how can have it to execute create2 instead of create?

Comment: In order to answer we would need to at least know the controller name, but it would be ideal if you could post the controller code handling this.  You would need a new method (create2) in the controller, route and form to handle this.

Comment: Ok I added example controller, form and route

Comment: Ya so you just need a new form to submit to the create2 method instead of create, the answer below can show you how to do that.  You may need a new "new" view to display the second from, unless there is a like a conditional to decide which one to show or something.

Comment: ok so the point is to specify url in the form. let me try...

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example your model is User with users_controller and you want to create another "new-create"

inside your routes you add some thing like this

```
resources :users do
  collection {
    get  :new_special_user
    post :create_special_user
  }
end
```

inside your users_controller you create 2 methods

```
def new_special_user

end

def create_special_user

end
```

inside new_special_user.html.erb, with url that will direct to create_special_user method in user contoller, below is the sample

```
<%= form_for @user, url: create_special_user_users_path do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. Thanks!